# How to convert fab.setOnclickListener(this) into kotlin.?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am writing code in kotlin.I want to know how to convert `fab.setOnclickListener(this)` into kotlin language.?

```
class MainActivity: appCompatActivity(){
   private var fab: FloatingActionButton? = null
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab)
     fab.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

**Expected**

Convert into kotlin

Comment: Why not just use `fab.setOnClickListener{}` ?

Comment: Then how I can pass `this`..?

Comment: its same , You just need to implement the `onClickListener` for activity

Comment: You don't need to pass `this`. Just write code logic inside `{}`

Comment: ok I will apply this and then let you know

Comment: also its `AppCompatActivity()` not `appCompatActivity()`

Comment: if you want to use `fab.setonclicklistener(this)` then you need your activity to implement the interface `View.OnClickListener`. If you don't want to implement the interface, then just pass in a lambda with the onclick logic `fab.setonclicklistener { //logic }`

Comment: I agree with you @JohnJoe, the `fab.setOnClickListener{}` approach is probably better

Comment: I only saw your comment now @ManoharReddy, but yes, the `onClickListener` implementation is how you'd achieve the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @John Joe is trying to say is that you can just use:

```
fab?.setOnClickListener { 
            //implement logic
        }
```

There's no need to be passing in `this` because `this` refers to the handler of the `setOnClickListener` method

so, you could also have it :

```
MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(),  View.OnClickListener{
 override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
   //handle logic for fab here    
    }
}
```

Which would then allow you to simply use:

```
fab?.setOnClickListener(this)
```

But, the first solution is way simpler.

---

Side note, because Kotlin has synthetic imports, you probably do not have to use `fab = findViewById(R.id.fab)` : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html